# Why is my Controller Action not being found?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a Controller in my Web API project that begins like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/pricecompliance")]
public class PriceComplianceController : ApiController
```

...and has a Get method with this routing:

```
[Route("api/pricecompliance/{unit}/{year}/{month}")] 
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit, string year, string shortmonth)
```

However, attempts to navigate to this URL:

```
http://localhost:52194/api/pricecompliance/GRAMPS/2016/Mar
```

...gives me Web API's 404 page.

If I reduce the route to this (since the controller already presumedly assumes the "api/pricecompliance" route prefix):

```
[Route("{unit}/{year}/{month}")]
```

..I get, "*No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost:52194/api/pricecompliance/GRAMPS/2016/Mar'*."

Why is the method not being found? I have other controllers that follow the same pattern, and their corresponding GET methods are found fine.

### UPDATE

Prepending the presumably superfluous "[HttpGet]" to the method does nothing to help matters, either.

### UPDATE 2

I still can't see how the code differs so that one works and the other doesn't. Here is the pertinent controller code:

PriceCompliance controller (not working):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/pricecompliance")]
public class PriceComplianceController : ApiController
. . .

[Route("{unit}/{year}/{month}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit, string year, string shortmonth)
{
    byte[] excelContents;
    . . .
```

ProduceUsage controller (is working):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/produceusage")]
public class ProduceUsageController : ApiController
. . .

    [Route("{unit}/{shortmonth}/{year}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit, string shortmonth, string year)
    {
        byte[] excelContents;
        . . .
```

Here is how the methods that provide the HTML are called:

PriceCompliance (not working):

```
var htmlStr = ConvertPriceComplianceFileBaseNameListToHtmlPartial(_FileBaseNameList, _unit);
return htmlStr;
```

ProduceUsage (is working):

```
var htmlStr = ConvertProduceUsageFileBaseNameListToHtmlPartial(_FileBaseNameList, _unit);
return htmlStr;
```

And here are those methods:

Price Compliance (not working):

```
internal static string ConvertPriceComplianceFileBaseNameListToHtmlPartial(List<string> _FileBaseNameList, string unit)
{
    string year;
    string shortmonth;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<h2>");
    builder.Append("Price Compliance");
    builder.Append("</h2>");
    builder.Append("<p></p>");

    // Create links for each report
    foreach (String fileBaseName in _FileBaseNameList)
    {
        year = GetElement(3, fileBaseName);
        shortmonth = GetElement(4, fileBaseName);
        string fileBaseNamePrettified = PrettifyPriceComplianceFBN(fileBaseName);
        builder.Append("<p></p>");
        builder.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"pricecompliance/{0}/{1}/{2}\">{3}</a>", unit, shortmonth, year, fileBaseNamePrettified)); 
        //http://localhost:52194/api/pricecompliance/GRAMPS/2016/Mar
        builder.Append("<p></p>");
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Produce Usage (is working):

```
internal static string ConvertProduceUsageFileBaseNameListToHtmlPartial(List<string> _FileBaseNameList, string unit)
{
    string year;
    string shortmonth;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<h2>");
    builder.Append("Produce Usage");
    builder.Append("</h2>");
    builder.Append("<p></p>");

    // Create links for each report
    foreach (String fileBaseName in _FileBaseNameList)
    {
        shortmonth = GetElement(3, fileBaseName);
        year = GetElement(4, fileBaseName);
        string fileBaseNamePrettified = PrettifyProduceUsageFBN(fileBaseName);
        builder.Append("<p></p>");
        builder.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"produceusage/{0}/{1}/{2}\">{3}</a>", unit, shortmonth, year, fileBaseNamePrettified));
        builder.Append("<p></p>");
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

I'm not grokking how one can be found and the other not when they are so clone-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route parameter is called `month` but your method parameter is called `shortmonth`:

> ```
> [Route("{unit}/{year}/{month}")]
> [HttpGet]
> public HttpResponseMessage Get(string unit, string year, string shortmonth)
> ```

This might be the reason behind your 404 errors, the model binding cannot bind `shortmonth` parameter (which is not optional) and thus complains.